# Apache, Centos, Passenger SQLite3 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am trying to run a Rails application on Centos with Apache
and I am getting this message in my browser:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

Looking in httpd logs I found that there is a SQLite3 issue.Any idea?

Environment:

```
Centos 6.5
64bit
Apache 2.2.15
ruby 2.0.0p481
Rails 4.0.5
passenger 4.0.48
```

Apache error-log

```
App 18313 stdout:
[ 2014-08-14 12:34:09.1836 18254/7f0c89077700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298 ]: Preloader for /var/www/html/masterbet_20140813 started on PID 18313, listening on unix:/tmp/p$

App 18402 stdout:
App 18402 stdout: Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.10 at 2014-08-14 12:34:09 +0300

App 18402 stdout: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML

App 18402 stdout: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd807$

App 18402 stdout: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
App 18402 stdout:

App 18402 stdout: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3$

App 18402 stdout:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `current_user'
App 18402 stdout:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:15:in `signed_in?'
App 18402 stdout:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:4:in `home'
```

Apache etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.masterbet.gr
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/masterbet_20140813/public
      <Directory /var/www/html/masterbet_20140813/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         #Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to use the apache through the passenger for my rails app. It seems that you need to point to your development db if you have initialized one or initialize the production db since you are in the production mode when deploying your app through apache by default. 
Go to the config/database.yml file and change the default configuration for the production: database: db/production.sqlite3 to database: db/development.sqlite3 if you have a development db ready. If not not you should run rake db:migrate and populate the production db.